# Low resolution of base64 images in webview

Tags: android, html, webview

I have html data in my database that contains images with base64 source and I am loading them through webview to show to the user.but the resolution of images is to low.What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, nice question :)
I don't know if webview is the problem but this runs on chrome.

> data:image/jpeg;base64,

At the very least is required
Look at these image codes very carefully

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />

<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
```

The similarities seen are

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxISEhUQDxIVFRUVFRcPFRAVFRUVFRAVFRUWFhUVFRUYHSogGBolHRUVIT0hJSkrMS4uGB8zODMsQygtLisBCgoKDg0OGhAQGy0lHyYtLS0vLS8rLS0tLystLS0tLS0tNSstLS8tLy0tLS4tLTUtKy8rKy0tLS0tLS0tLS0tL

Most likely, ↑that↑ is the needed code to start base64 image code. But, just to be safe, it could be only what I stated earlier:

> data:image/jpeg;base64,

Comment: Then html viewer is the problem